# Windows 7 in an XP box

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation

I have an HP Media Computer with the following:

HP Pavilion
Intel Pentium D CPU 2.80GHz
2,80 GHz  2.00GB of Ram 
Physical Address Extension
MS Windows XP
Media Center Edition
Version 2002
Service Pack 3

What would have to be done in order for this box to run current versions of Windows 7?
Is the buss in this old box too slow for the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor) This program should inspect your hardware to see if it is fit for Windows 7.

It does seem like your computer specs fulfill the system requirements for Windows 7 though. It should run Windows 7 just fine.